# check to see if vector index is empty

Tags: c++, vector

In my code, I need to do this:

```
if (edges[j].ConnectedToNode() != i) //problem line
{
    edges.push_back(Edge(i, j, nodes[i].Position(), nodes[j].Position(), distanceToNode)); 
}
```

however, there is a possibility that edges[j] does not exist yet. how can I test for this to avoid and index out-of-range exception? (This is to do with path nodes, essentially if there is an edge connecting j to i, I don't want to add another from i to j.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing indices. You are using j as an index for edges and also as an index for the nodes.  push_back will append a copy of the Edge object you are creating to the edges array.  It won't necessarily go to the jth index.  Consider using the boost::graph library.

Comment: you're absolutely right, I'm in the middle of updating my code and edges is changing from a vector to a vector of maps from indices to edges

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before accessing `edges[j]` check that `j < edges.size()`.

EDIT:

To illustrate what Mark Ransom commented:

```
if (j < edges.size() && edges[j].ConnectedToNode() != i) //problem line
{
    edges.push_back(Edge(i, j, nodes[i].Position(), nodes[j].Position(), distanceToNode)); 
}
```

Comment: This is where the short-circuiting behavior of `&&` and `||` comes in handy - you can put that check first in the `if` statement and the second part won't won't be executed, so there's no chance of out-of-range access.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking the size of the vector:

```
if(edges.size() <= i) // will be false if i is too large
```

If this is the case, you have to resize the vector:

```
    edges.resize(j + 1);
```

Depending on the density of your adjacency-list, you will get a very sparse vector (most entries will not be used). In that case you should consider using a `std::map<int, int>` or something like that. This has the benefit that a map automatically creates a new index, if none exists for the given key.

Comment: why would I have to resize the vector?

Comment: I thought your formulation *"does not exist **yet**"* indicated that you want to create an entry if it doesn't exist. Seems I have misinterpreted.