# Using pair<int, int> as key for map

Tags: c++, dictionary, std-pair

Based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016197/stdmapint-int-vs-vector-of-vector), I am trying to create a map using a pair of integers as a key i.e. `map<pair<int, int>, int>` and I've found information on how to insert:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
map<pair<int, int>, int> mymap;

mymap.insert(make_pair(make_pair(1,2), 3)); //edited
}
```

but I can't seem to access the element! I've tried `cout << mymap[(1,2)] << endl;` but it shows an error, and I can't find information on how to access the element using the key. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `cout << mymap[make_pair(1,2)] << endl;` ?

Comment: `(1,2)` is non-sensical, at least in this context. You must have an `std::pair` to be used as your key, and that means following what @andre just commented.

Comment: Yes! I'm a dolt. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! For future reference, please post the complete error message when you ask a question about fixing one.

Comment: This could work `mymap[{1,2}]`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you need a pair as a key `cout << mymap[make_pair(1,2)] << endl;` What you currently have `cout << mymap[(1,2)] << endl;` is not the correct syntax.

Answer (score 13):

`mymap[make_pair(1,2)]`

or, with compiler support:

`mymap[{1,2}]`

Answer (score 6):

Please find the code for the reference:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

   map<pair<int ,int> ,int > m;
   m.insert({{1, 2}, 100});
   cout << m[{1, 2}];
}
```