# How do I create a key that contains two words for a hashmap?

Tags: c++

I have written a code that uses a hashmap to create a new textfile. In my original code, a key is one word. How do I make keys that contain two words?

```
ifstream infile(fn.c_str(), ios::in); // open file
string key = "";
string value = "";
infile >> key;
ht->first = key;
while (infile >> value) { // loop getting single characters
    cout << key << ": " << value << endl;
    ht->addKeyValue(key, value);
    key = value;   
    value = "";
}
ht->addKeyValue(key,value);
cout << endl;
infile.close();
```

Comment: You can use a [multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/), with `std::pair<string, string>`

Comment: If you need to have *a pair of words* as a key for a hashmap, you could do exactly that. [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016646/using-pairint-int-as-key-for-map).

Comment: The key can be a string (which might have spaces). There's nothing special about a text word, as far as the map class is concerned. Basically, "just do it."

Comment: What do you mean by "two words"? `key1 + " " + key2`?

Comment: `ifstream infile(fn.c_str(),ios::in);` can be `ifstream infile(fn);``ifstream` implies `ios::in` and as of the C++11 Standard revision, all `fstream`s accept `string`s.