# C++ map using pair as key

Tags: c++, dictionary, containers, std-pair

I am using a map (which seemed the best implementation after a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016197/stdmapint-int-vs-vector-of-vector), with a pair key, as a 'container' for incoming messages that can be sorted according to sourceID and priority i.e. key: (sourceID, priority) which points to an int value.
Processing will happen 'on' this map.

I've just come against a problem - I need to do something like this pseudo code to subsequently retrieve messages:

```
map<pair<int, int>, int> mymap;

if (!mymap[make_pair(nodeID,i)].empty()) //i refers to all the priority levels
    //processing occurs here to retrieve a value
```

but I can't seem to do it easily. Is there a way to do this simply without running an iterator e.g. `for (i = 0; i <priority ; i++)`? I know that if I used an equivalent `vector<vector<int>>` I would be able to do this easily, but a map works better for my program at the moment.

edit:

The messages are sorted into the map by (sourceID, priority level), and then processed before being mapped into another map by (destID, priority level). I need to check there there are messages available for any particular destID, regardless of priority level, so I am looking for an easy way to check this.

I know that if I use a `vector<vector<int>>`, I will be able to do something like `node[2].empty()`, if I want to check that node 2 has no available messages. Is there an equivalent for maps?

Comment: Huh? Your pseudocode doesn't make sense to me. `mymap[make_pair(nodeID,i)]` is an `int`, you can't call `empty()` on that. Can you describe more clearly what you're trying to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using pair<int, int> as key for map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016646/using-pairint-int-as-key-for-map)

Comment: Why are you re-posting your question?

Comment: The question is different, I'll edit it now to be more clear.

Comment: You need `mymap.find(make_pair(nodeID,i)) != mymap.end()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand things correctly, you'd like a convenient way to determine how many entries `(node_id,i)` the map has, where `node_id` is fixed and `i` can be anything.

If this understanding is correct, you can make use of the fact that the ordering inside your map is based on the ordering defined by `std::less<std::pair<int,int>>`, which by default is the lexicographical ordering. In other words, the node-id will be used as the main sorting criterion, whereas the second element of the pair will be used as secondary sorting criterion.

You can therefore use the `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` functions of the map to determine the range of entries for a given node-id as follows (C++11 code, but can be converted to C++03):

```
std::ptrdiff_t num_per_node(const mymap &map, const int node_id)
{
  using std::distance;
  static constexpr int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
  static constexpr int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

  auto lo = map.lower_bound({node_id,min});
  auto hi = map.upper_bound({node_id,max});
  return distance(lo,hi);
}
```

The function defined above returns the number of entries there are in the map `map` for the given node-id `node_id`.

So your pseudo-code becomes:

```
if (num_per_node(mymap,nodeID) > 0)
```

The function has logarithmic complexity, which is clearly (asymptotically) better than iterating through all priority values.

Note that this only works because the elements of your pairs are `int`, so it is readily possible to establish minimum and maximum values. Again, it also only works because of the lexicographical ordering. If you use a customised comparator function with your map, this method will no longer work, and whether a corrsponding method can be found depends on how exactly your comparator is defined.

Here is a GIT-gist with a complete example that demonstrates how the function can be used: https://gist.github.com/jogojapan/5027365

Answer (score 1):

Just to build on what @jogojapan has done, I've adapted it to not use C++11 (because I'm not using it), and leaving it here for reference. Not sure it does *everything* his does, but works sufficiently for me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <limits>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

std::ptrdiff_t num_per_node(const map<pair<int, int>, int> &map, const int node_id)
{
  using std::distance;
  static int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
  static int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    auto lo = map.lower_bound(make_pair(node_id,min));
    auto hi = map.upper_bound(make_pair(node_id,max));
    return distance(lo,hi);
  }

  int main() {
    map<pair<int, int>, int> m;
    m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(1,3),1));
    m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(3,4),2));
    m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(3,5),3));
    m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(3,9),4)); 
    m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(4,2),5)); 
    m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(4,3),6)); 
    m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(5,1),7)); 
    m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(8,2),8));

    for (int node_id = 0 ; node_id < 10 ; ++node_id)
      std::cout << "node-id " << node_id << ": " << num_per_node(m,node_id) << '\n';

    return 0;
  }
```

which correctly returns

```
node-id 0: 0
node-id 1: 1
node-id 2: 0
node-id 3: 3
node-id 4: 2
node-id 5: 1
node-id 6: 0
node-id 7: 0
node-id 8: 1
node-id 9: 0
```

Comment: +1 for your efforts. Actually, you must be using C++11 somewhere, because apparently it accepts our use of `auto`, which is strictly C++11. Here is a fully C++03 version with typedefs instead of my using-aliases: http://liveworkspace.org/code/4xo1cJ$2

Comment: I think mine was a crib of yours, @jogojapan (totally new to this). I merely tried to correct what was being red-underlined in vbcpp2010. I can't seem to access your link!

Comment: [This link](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4xo1cJ$2) is hopefully correct. That was either a Markdown formatting issue, or a copy/pasting mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution could be using 2 nested maps:

```
typedef std::map<int,int> priorities;
typedef std::map<int,priorities> messages;
```

Find if there is any message for given sourceId and any priority becomes trivial for price of 2 lookups when you need to find message with given sopurceId and priority.